# javascript es6: import destructuring not working

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Have redux files set up in a `modules` folder:

```
\modules
    \application
        \actions
            application.js
            index.js
        \records
            application.js
        \reducers
            application.js
            index.js
```

My `application` record is an Immutable record that exports a default:

```
import {Record, List, Map, Set, OrderedMap} from 'immutable';

const Application = new Record({
    'loaded': false,
});

export default {
    Application,
};
```

In my `reducers/application.js` file, I destructure the export on import:

```
import {Record, List, Map, Set, OrderedMap} from 'immutable';
import { Application } from '../records/application';

import 
    APP_INITIALIZE
from '../actions';

const initialAppState = new Application();

export default (state = initialAppState, action )=> {
    switch (action.type) {

    case APP_INITIALIZE:
        return state
                .set('loaded', true);

    default:
        return state;
    }
};
```

I would expect this to work because `records/application.js` exports an object, which contains the immutable record. However, I get the following error:

`application.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: _records_application__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.Application is not a constructor`

And when I inspect the `Application` object inside `reducers/application.js`, I get `undefined`.

My `.babelrc` file looks like this:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-react",
    ["@babel/preset-env", {
      "useBuiltIns": "usage",
      "corejs": 2,
      "targets": {
          "firefox": "64",
          "chrome": "58",
          "ie": "11",
          "electron": "4"   
      },
    }]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
  ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Stop using `default` exports if you want to actually selectively import (which is what destructuring is). Or, if you absolutely need `default` exports, stop selectively importing and import the module as a namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to import a default export which is an object *and* destructure it at the same time, because that syntax clashes with the syntax of importing *named* exports from the other file. Your

```
import { Application } from '../records/application';
```

tries to import the *named export* named `Application` from the other file, but it has no such named export, so things break.

The `{`s after `import` indicate that you're importing something that's named; no `{`s indicates that you're importing the default.

You can import the default and destructure on the next line:

```
import FullApplication from '../records/application';
const { Application } = FullApplication;
```

If that other file really doesn't have anything else in it, it would make more sense to make the `Application` record the default export:

```
const Application = new Record({
    'loaded': false,
});
export default Application;
```

```
import Application from '../records/application';
```

Or you could name the `Application` export, and have no default export:

```
export const Application = new Record({
    'loaded': false,
});
```

```
import { Application } from '../records/application';
```

Comment: See [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#description) for more details and links to specs. To summarize, there are 4 kinds of static imports in total. Only one of them has curly braces, which is **named import** and has the syntax `import { foo } from 'module'`. You cannot use this syntax to import defaut exports.